# Simple Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run this stored procedure using this:

```
EXECUTE RecipeDetails.sp_InsertRecipe
    @title='gumbo',
    @introdution='intro',
    @ingredients='onion',
    @difficulty='easy',
    @prepTimeHour=null,
    @prepTimeMinute=null,
    @inactiveTimeHour=null,
    @inactiveTimeMinute=null,
    @servings=null,
    @photo=null
```

I get an error saying

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure sp_InsertRecipe, Line 0
>
> Procedure or function
>   'sp_InsertRecipe' expects parameter
>   '@introduction', which was not
>   supplied.

Can some please advise me as to why it's saying "introduction" isn't a valid column name?

I have the following SQL Server stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [RecipeDetails].[sp_InsertRecipe]
@title varchar(50),
@introduction varchar(255),
@directions varchar(2200),
@ingredients varchar(2200),
@difficulty varchar(6), or "expert"*/
@prepTimeHour tinyint,
@prepTimeMinute tinyint,
@inactiveTimeHour tinyint,
@inactiveTimeMinute tinyint,
@servings tinyint,
@photo varbinary(MAX)

AS

BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 INSERT INTO RecipeDetails.Recipe (title, introduction, ingredients, difficulty, 
 prepTimeHour, prepTimeMinute, inactiveTimeHour, inactiveTimeMinute, servings, photo)
 VALUES (@title, @introduction, @ingredients, @difficulty, @prepTimeHour, @prepTimeMinute,@inactiveTimeHour, @inactiveTimeMinute, @servings, @photo)
END
GO
```

Comment: You shouldn't name any objects with an `sp_` prefix. SQL Server searches for such objects in the master db first, and it's pretty well reserved for MS to use for naming their objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple typo: see your call to the stored proc:

```
EXECUTE RecipeDetails.sp_InsertRecipe
    @title='gumbo',
    @introdution='intro',   <== TYPO HERE !! Should be @introduction !!
    @ingredients='onion',
```

You've supplied a parameter `@introdution` - but **not** `@introduction`  (you're missing a "c" in that name there)

Answer (score 4):

If this code is verbatim to what you're running, then it's because you've misspelled "Introduction" when you call the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You have Misspelled Your Field `@Introduction` as `'@Introdution'`

I have Done Corrections Here:

```
EXECUTE RecipeDetails.sp_InsertRecipe
@title='gumbo',
@introduction='intro',
@ingredients='onion',
@difficulty='easy',
@prepTimeHour=null,
@prepTimeMinute=null,
@inactiveTimeHour=null,
@inactiveTimeMinute=null,
@servings=null,
@photo=null
```